# Add a twig variable to an <img>

Tags: html, image, symfony, twig

I have an image showing up like that:

```
src="{{ asset('./images/cours/zumba.jpg') }}"
```

Then I define a foo variable:

```
{% set foo = 'zumba' %}
```

Then I try to insert the variable foo in the `<img>`

```
src="{{ asset('./images/cours/{{ foo }}.jpg') }}"
```

The image doesn't show up, any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must rather do :

```
src="{{ asset('./images/cours/' ~ foo ~ '.jpg') }}"
```

`~` is to concatenate strings, so it concatenates your variable and the placeholder path that you have.

See the *"Other operators"* section [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) for the complete documentation